# Mounting volume from CI container into docker-compose container

Tags: docker, docker-compose, continuous-integration, circleci, docker-volume

We're using CircleCI for a project, with the default `docker` execution type. This means that each CI job that gets kicked off starts a new Docker container, and the build runs *inside* that container.

This CI container has the following files:

```
docker-compose.yml
sql-setup.sql
```

This `docker-compose.yml` file starts a MySQL image and uses `volumes` to copy the SQL script inside so it's ready at startup, like:

```
  mysql:
    image: mysql:8.0.18
    ...
    volumes:
      - ./sql-setup.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/sql-setup.sql
```

(This works on a local developer machine.)

**The Problem** is that when running on CI, the `docker-compose up` in the 'parent' CI container creates a 'child/sibling' container with:

```
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root   40 Jul  8 17:26 sql-setup.sql
```

*Note it's a directory!*

My debugging suggests this is because `./sql-setup.sql` doesn't exist on the **host**. (Only on the CI container running *on the host*.)

**My Question:** How can I configure my `docker-compose.yml` (or my CircleCI config) so that the file from the CI container (which is running `docker-compose up`) gets copied properly into the resulting `mysql` compose container?

Answer (score -1):

Using `machine` executor instead of `docker` executor solves this

Ref: https://discuss.circleci.com/t/copying-files-to-docker-compose-container/12837

Comment: It's always good to add main descriptions from the link. The link can be not accessible in the future.